# What happened to github topics?

Tags: github

GitHub began to show only a small proportion of repositories on [GitHub-topics](https://github.com/topics/). 
Pieces 10 maximum, although previously there was an unlimited number (how many repositories exist in this tag)

Is this a policy change or my problem? I cleaned the cache, cookie, checked from different browsers and nothing has changed.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to a forum or Twitter, not on SO network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also surprised by this, as the topics feature is useful and there is not much information on whether this is a bug or a policy change. After some research, I found this [post](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/quot-Topics-quot-page-has-changed/td-p/37765) on the GitHub community forum that discusses it. A work around is to use the manual search for the moment.

After contacting the GitHub support's team, this is their answer:

> Thank you for writing in to GitHub Support and I'm sorry you have
>   experienced this problem.
>
> We have had a few reports of this bug and our engineers are looking
>   into it. It's very useful for us to have more data points, so thank
>   you for submitting this report! I'll pass it on to the team.
>
> I can't make any promises around specific changes or updates, but
>   please trust that your report is in good hands.